# can I create a table inwhich each cell has multiple column using php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to create a table with two columns - name and courses. So, let's say for the first row, I want to insert John into the name column, and insert maths, English, chemistry into the courses column(the same row as name-John). Is this possible with php/mysql.

Comment: Do you mean insert a comma separated list of courses into a column in a MySQL table? Don't do it; normalize your data tables properly, otherwise you'll cause yourself eternal grief, create a system that is slow and inefficient, and be forever having to ask for help with all the problems that you've created for yourself

Comment: See normalisation.

Comment: I mean a kind of list in which I can select each of it values. For example I may wish to select chemistry.

Answer (score 0):

You can save 3 rows with name set to John for each of Maths, Chemistry and English.

Just add another column asy '`name_id`' which is same for the three rows.

That way, if you want to see this particular John's subjects, you can fetch his subjects `SELECT courses FROM student_db WHERE name_id="xx"`

That would be a easier way.

If you want a single row for John then

`INSERT INTO student_db (name,courses) VALUES ('John','Maths,Chemistry,English')`

should work.